# RewriteRule clearing post data

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
<Directory /var/www/website/html>
        Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        RewriteEngine on

        # Enforce removal of trailing slash
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

        # If the user is performing a search
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=([^&]+)
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1&query=%1 [L,B]

        # If the user has a token set
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^token=([^&]+)
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1&token=%1 [L,B]

        # If not existing file/directory, redirect to index.php
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [L,B]
</Directory>
```

When posting data to a directory on my server with the `QUERY_STRING` condition above, it appears that the `RewriteRule` is clearing the post data.

I am looking to modify this `RewriteRule` so that post data is still accessible when these conditions stated are met.

Comment: Are there more rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava Updated with full Directory listing in `apache2.conf`, the rule I am referring to is the one commented with "If the user has a token set"

Comment: Does your post request URL has a trailing slash?

Comment: @anubhava Yes it does. Spot on - I've removed that and it works now. Could you advise how I should modify the rules so that this isn't a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this to avoid redirect when `REQUEST_METHOD` is `POST`:

```
<Directory /var/www/website/html>
        Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        RewriteEngine on

        # Enforce removal of trailing slash except for POST request
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301,NE]

        # skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # If the user is performing a search
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1&query=%1 [L,B,QSA]

        # If the user has a token set
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^token=
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1&token=%1 [L,B,QSA]

        # If not existing file/directory, redirect to index.php
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [L,B,QSA]
</Directory>
```

I've refactored some rules to avoid redundant conditions. Also use `QSA` flags to append previous query string.